# Ruby on Rails, How to connect 2 tables on different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three tables that look like this:

```
user -> id | nickname | email | pass
role -> id | name 
user_roles -> id | user_id | role_id
```

I'm trying like that because one user could have a lot of roles I want to check roles like this: `User.roles`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a classic use case for a `has_many :through` association ([docs here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)). Specifically:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end
```